# como faz para colocar um arquivo local para download em flask ou python?

Tags: python, flask

tinha que fazer o download de um arquivo em python ou flask eu tentei assim mas acho que apenas abre o arquivo

```
@app.route("/downloads/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def orac_detal():
                global datas, listaComTudo, nomesDespesas, df          
                state = {'gera':0, 'gera_total_csv':0, 'gera_orcamento':0, 'gera_total':0, 'taxas':0, 'gera_agrupamento':0, 'orac_detal':1}

                m = np.zeros((156,96))



                for loja in lojas:
                    if os.path.isfile("./.pickles/orcamentoAux_"+str(loja)+".pickle"):
                        with open(r"./.pickles/orcamentoAux_"+str(loja)+".pickle", "rb") as input_file:
                            foo = pickle.load(input_file)
                            datas = foo['datas'] # lista com todas as datas, para ser o cabeçalho da planilha
                            listaComTudo = foo['listaComTudo'] # lista de lista, em que cada lista interna tem os dados de uma despesa
                            nomesDespesas = foo['nomesDespesas'] # lista com o nome de todas as despesas, para ser inserida no final usando a função de colocar na primeira coluna


                for i in range(len(listaComTudo)):
                    m[i] += listaComTudo[i]

                for i in range(len(listaComTudo)):
                    nomesDespesas[i] = nomesDespesas[i].replace(","," ")
                    listaComTudo[i] = [nomesDespesas[i]] + listaComTudo[i]

                dicionario = {}
                for i in range(len(nomesDespesas)):
                    chave = nomesDespesas[i][23:]
                    dicionario[chave] = m[i] 

                df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=dicionario, orient='index', columns=datas)

                writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
                    'despesas_detal.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
                df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')    
                writer.save()

                return df.to_csv('despesas_detal.csv',mode='a')

def return_files_tut():
        try:
            return send_file('/home/orbistec2/delphos_3.0/despesas_detal.xlsx', attachment_filename='despesas_detal.xlsx')
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplesmente crie uma pasta chamada `static` e coloque o arquivo lá; O flask cria a rota para essa pasta automaticamente.

Então é só direcionar o download para o link; Você pode usar a função `url_for` do flask para gerar o link correto: `

```
return redirect(url_for('static', filename='despesas_detal.xlsx'))
```

Uma outra forma menos comum é retornar os bytes diretamente. Você pode passar bytes para o `make_response`:

```
with open('arquivo.xlsx', 'rb') as f: 
     dados = f.read() # le o arquivo binariamente
return make_response((dados, 
    {'content-type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'))
```

Comment: return redirect(url_for('.static','despesas_detal.csv')) , ele acusa esse erro : TypeError: url_for() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Tenta assim, @matheusteixeira: `return redirect(url_for('static', filename='despesas_detal.xlsx'))` adicionando o parâmetro `filename`.

Comment: é isso mesmo, eu esqueci do `filename` - editei a resposta @IgorCavalcanti obrigado